# How can i create nested tabsets in R flexdashboard?

Tags: r, layout, flexdashboard

I dont know if it is actually possible but im looking to create nested tabsets in my R flexdashboard layout.

I know how to insert tabs into rows of my flexdashboard layout but i have no clue how to insert subtabs nested in the previous one.

My code look like this :

````
---
title: "Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    storyboard: true
    orientation: rows
    social: menu
    source: embed
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)```

Sheet 1 
===================================== 
Row {data-height=500}
-------------------------------------
### Chart A

### Chart B

Row {.tabset}
-------------------------------------

### Chart C

### Chart D
````

It produces this layout :

[Flexdashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS95x.png)

What i would like is a new tab under Chart C to introduce Chart C.1 and Chart C.2 for example.

I've been looking for answers and stackoverflow and didnt find anything related to the subject.

I noticed there were solutions for shiny users but im building a flexdashboard without shiny.

Thank you in advance for your answers.